# How to map property of entity using EF

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-7.0

The title might be a bit off but I do not have a better idea on how to present my problem.

I have a user, and that user belongs to a category, but instead of the categoryId that is used to keep track of what category that user belongs, I want to map category name when I return all users dto.

```cs
// Entities
public partial class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNr { get; set; }
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  // Navigation Properties
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}

// DTOs
public class UserDto : IMapFrom<User>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNr { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; } // --> Want to map CategoryName instead
}

// Get all Users
    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> Handle(GetAllUsersQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var data = await _context.Users
                 .ProjectTo<UserDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                 .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure Automapper to retrieve the category name
`CreateMap<User, UserDto>() .ForMember(dest => dest.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category.CategoryName));`

So when the mapping from user to user dto will be done, the category name will be retrieved instead of the id.